# Is it possible to fail "mvn package" for not meeting JaCoCo code coverage requirements?

Tags: java, maven, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

I have included the JaCoCo maven plugin in my project's POM

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.7</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>default-report</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>default-check</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <rules>
                    <rule>
                        <element>BUNDLE</element>
                        <limits>
                            <limit>
                                <counter>LINE</counter>
                                <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                <minimum>0.70</minimum>
                            </limit>
                        </limits>
                    </rule>
                </rules>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I noticed that only the following commands fail when the code coverage requirements is not met:

- `mvn verify`
- `mvn install`
- `mvn deploy`

Is it possible to configure the JaCoCo plugin to fail the `mvn package` command as well?

Comment: During which phase does jacoco run? If it runs during any phase before package - it will do what you want, otherwise it just won't run so won't fail :)

Comment: That helped, thank you for making me think in the right direction ^_^. 

I added `<phase>package</phase>` to the `check` execution which makes JaCoCo run during the package phase.

Comment: An after thought, it will probably be better to make it run in the `test` phase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure your `check` goal to run on the `prepare-package` phase. `prepare-package` phase runs just before the `package` goal. This way, your build will fail if the coverage rules are not met.

Here is how your `pom.xml` will change.

```xml
<execution>
    <id>default-check</id>
    <goals>
        <goal>check</goal>
    </goals>
    <phase>prepare-package</phase> <!-- Fail just before package phase is executed -->
    <configuration>
        <rules>
            <!-- Rule configuration here -->
        </rules>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```

Checkout the [documentation for Maven Lifecycle Goals for phases](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.5/maven-core/lifecycles.html) and the order in which they are executed.